# UK VAT unique invoice number

Tags: vat

I've recently registered for VAT and I'm not sure if I've been numbering my invoices correctly.

I don't have many clients and I simply run a sequential count so it would be invoice #01...#02..#03

every new client has their own sequence starting from #01 although I don't have a specific client identifier on the invoice number so it could be that I end up with invoice #01 for client A and also client B..

is this correct/acceptable or should I make sure numbers are unique for every client?

Comment: Uhhh, what? I don't understand what the dilemma is?

Comment: I just number mine from YYMM01, so that this month I have 180901, 180902 ... but I only have one client. If I had more, I would probably add a unique client Id at the start, but my method as it stands works even for multiple clients.

Answer (score 1):

I have no knowledge of VAT (because I'm US-based and don't need it).

However, customarily **every** invoice has a **unique** number - regardless of client/customer. You should **never** have more than 1 invoice with the same number, ever. This allows you to find the **exact** transaction at a later date. Having multiple invoices with identical numbers will inevitably result in a nightmare.

If you have multiple invoices, all numbered as #01.... then you'll be scouring every 01 invoice to try and find the correct one. That's not good. It may seem minor with 50 invoices, but after a couple years you may have thousands of invoices to wade through.

Again, without VAT knowledge here ... you *can* add a unique client identifier to invoice numbers if you'd like. I do, just to make it easier to find those "jobs" in my tracking. How you add that identifier is kind of up to you. The important aspect is that no 2 invoices *ever* have the same number. As far as I'm aware the *only* rule regarding invoice numbers is that the be unique. (If VAT is different and someone knows, please comment to let me know I'm mistaken for VAT).

For a client ID:
You could use a range of things... 
from `#001-001` where the first three digits would be the client ID
Or `#AAA001` where the first 3 alpha characters are the client ID.

I, personally, add the year to my invoice numbers as well as a client identifier. As in `18AAAA0001` --18 for the year AAAA for the client, followed by the actual invoice number. This allows me to typically keep invoice numbers to 4 digits since the year changes every 12 months. So I can have unique invoices numbers such as `17AAAA0300` and `18AAAA0300`.

In a list, this generally sorts the numbers by year-client-invoice which I find helpful.

Merely forward thinking -- I'd suggest all invoices have a *minimum* of 4 digits (if not 5 or 6) with leading zeroes. It'll merely makes things more organized once you start getting a record of many invoices.

Answer (score 1):

The gov.uk website has some useful information on how to invoice customers and what information needs to be included on an invoice. See https://www.gov.uk/invoicing-and-taking-payment-from-customers.

Invoice numbers need to be unique across the business, not per customer:

> You must include ... a unique identification number

There are some additional requirements for VAT invoices:

> Include the following on your invoice ... **a unique invoice number that follows on from the last invoice**

A single sequential counter for numbering your invoices as you send them fulfills this, eg: invoice 1 to client A, invoice 2 to client B, invoice 3 to client A, and so on.